# Using conda to install LaTeX on Mac

Tags: python, latex, conda, spyder

Is there a way to use conda to install LaTeX on a Mac? I use Spyder and I am having trouble getting LaTeX to work to format figures.

I tried just downloading LaTeX from http://www.tug.org/mactex/, but that seems unrelated to Spyder. I also tried installing Miktex with conda, but that seems to be for Windows only.

Edit: I'm using macOS Mojave version 10.14.6. I see on the MacTeX [website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html):

"When Apple produced El Capitan, they modified the system so users could no longer write directly to the /usr directory and this rule remains in effect today. Therefore we replaced /usr/texbin with /Library/TeX/texbin."

I'm not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: Yes, MacTeX is unrelated to Spyder, but why should that matter?

Comment: I would like to have a version of LaTeX that can be used by Spyder, if possible.

Comment: A version of LaTeX that you install using MacTeX should be able to be used by Spyder. You will need to install links into the standard system directories (there's an option for this in the installer), or tell Spyder where you installed MacTeX. Did you try something and get an error message?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do either of those things — can you provide any pointers?

Comment: When you run the installer for MacTeX, there should be a button to check to provide links to directories like `/usr/local`. Make sure to check that box, and it should work.

Comment: Sorry for being difficult here, but I just ran the installer and I didn't see any options like this (or any options at all, for that matter). Can you elaborate on how I would tell Spyder where to look? I tried adding /Applications/TeX to the PYTHONPATH manager, but that was unsuccessful. That was the only thing I could find to add to PYTHONPATH, so maybe that's the wrong thing to be using.

Comment: I think it might be that you have to click a button to "customize the installation"... or some such. You'll need to be editing your `PATH`, not `PYTHONPATH`, since these are not Python packages, but regular executables

Answer (score 1):

As LaTeX is kind of an independent ecosystem (from Honda and python), I would recommend using the official distribution instead:

https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Most programs there (TexShop, BibDesk, ...) come with their own update mechanism - and TexLiveUtility allows to update tex packages as your need them.

note: I have also previously used homebrew, but I found the system quite redundant with that proposed by MacTex.

Answer (score -1):

I was exactly in the same configuration as you. I tried writing `conda install latexcodec` in the spyder terminal and that fixed it.